# Why JavaScript function not fired when a check changed is triggered in the browser's console?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to JavaScript/jQuery, while learning I found something strange for me. Basically, I have a function that capture the checkbox check state.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="accs" class="forsummary" name="Accessory">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('change keyup keypress','.forsummary',function(){

  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      console.log("This is checked");
  }else{
     console.log("This is unchecked");
  }  

});
```

this code works when the trigger is done within the website, But when I run this code In the browser's console, the function is not fired:

```
$('#accs').prop('checked', false);
```

Can anyone provide me the simplest explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Events are only triggered when the property is changed by the user, not when it's changed by code.

Comment: Add `.trigger("change")` to the end to force the event handler to run.

Comment: @Barmar this is very helpful. Thanks, but when I try adding the .trigger("change")  still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try between them

```js
document.querySelector('.forsummary').addEventListener('change', function (el) {
  if (el.target.checked) {
    console.log("This is checked");
  }else{
    console.log("This is unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="accs" class="forsummary" name="Accessory">
```

```js
function checkbox_status (el) {
  if (el.checked) {
    console.log("This is checked");
  }else{
    console.log("This is unchecked");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkbox_status(this)" name="Accessory">
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you add wrong selector filter to jquery `on`.you set a none exists class `.forsummary` selector.I chagne it to `#accs`,it works.you can run my code to test it

```js
$(document).on('change keyup keypress','.forsummary',function(){

  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      console.log("This is checked");
  }else{
     console.log("This is unchecked");
  }  

});
setTimeout(function(){
$("#accs").trigger("click")
console.log("trigger")
},1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="accs" class="forsummary" name="Accessory">
```

Comment: I have updated my questions. since I have many forsummary classes?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, what @Barmar mentioned works quite well only thing is I fired the event using click that will anyway make a change

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".forsummary").change(function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
    console.log('true');
  }else{
  console.log('false');
  }
});

setTimeout(function(){
$("#accs").trigger("click");
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="accs" class="forsummary" name="Accessory">
```